# Recommended way to get the children of the default slot (Native web components)

Tags: javascript

Say I have a web component with multiple slots. I wish to get all the children of the default (unamed) slot **only**. I could add an ID or class to the default slot, and select `querySelector` it, but I suspect there is a built in way to access the children of it's default slot directly.

The following example prints all children, i.e. those from the `other` slot, which I am not interested in:

```
  "0": <p>Slotted 1</p>,
  "1": <p>Slotted 2</p>,
  "2": <p slot="other">Ignore this one</p>,
```

In this example I would just like to get the first 2 elements because they are from the default (unnamed) slot.

```js
 customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {   
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE");
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
   }
   connectedCallback() {
       setTimeout( ()=> {
          console.log(this.children)
       }, 100);
   }
 });
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE">   
   <slot></slot>
   <slot name="other"></slot>   
</template>

<my-element>
   <p>Slotted 1</p>
   <p>Slotted 2</p>
   <p slot="other">Ignore this one</p>
</my-element>
```

Comment: Can you not just filter `[...this.children]` on whether or not there's a `slot` attribute?